# Robot Framework If element is visible execute a keyword

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a page that may and may not contain a certain element that will affect all the xpaths.

I need to run a "Run Keyword If" to identify if this element exists and if so to execute another keyword.

I tried to set the "Page Should Contain Element" and "Element Should Be Visible" as variables and pass it in the If statement but it only return None.

What can I use to identify an element in a page?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I experienced the same issue, I use this solution:

```
${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=my-element
Run Keyword If    ${present}    My Cool Keyword
```

Comment: One (relatively minor) downside to this solution is that it runs the run-on-failure hook which is 'Capture Page Screenshot' by default, wasting time and disk space.

Comment: @MariusGedminas, so do you have another solution?

Comment: I use this solution, but I wrap it with `${fail keyword}=    Register keyword to run on failure    No operation` and `Register keyword to run on failure    ${fail keyword}`.

Comment: @MariusGedminas bit confused how the wrapping would work, so what you would have done is - ${fail keyword}=    Register keyword to run on failure    No operation ${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=my-element
Run Keyword If    ${present}    My Cool Keyword Register keyword to run on failure    ${fail keyword}, is this right?

Comment: Is it possible to do it in one line?   
Like IF  KeywordReturningElementStatus   My Cool Keyword   
*** Keyword ***   
KeywordReturningElementStatus      
${status}=   Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   id=my-element   
[Return]   ${status}

Comment: where do you declare ${present} variable? I am getting an error Variable '${present}' not found.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar situation and I used the script below:

```
${IsElementVisible}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   ${Element1}
Run Keyword If    ${IsElementVisible}  MyCase1  ELSE  Click Element  ${Element2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a faster and less wordy alternative:

```
${c} =   Get Element Count   ${locator}
Run Keyword If   ${c}>0    Call Your Keyword Here
```

Comment: But this won't check visibility, only presence in the DOM, right?

Comment: Right-o, YMMV... ;)